# Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE and retain part of it

Tags: regex, oracle, unicode, oracle10g

I have a text in the column, something like

```
Hello World %UC#abc#UC%. How are you %UC#def#UC%. Have a nice day %UC#ghi#UC%.
```

I want to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` (or any) function to replace `%UC#< value >#UC%` with `UNISTR(< value >)`. From the above example, the result should be

```
Hello World (UNISTR of abc). How are you (UNISTR of def). Have a nice day (UNISTR of ghi).
```

Basically it should strip off `%UC#` and replace the value within it with the `UNISTR` of the value.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a way in 11g and on:

```
with test(s) as ( select 'Hello World %UC#abc#UC%. How are you %UC#def#UC%. Have a nice day %UC#ghi#UC%.' || '%UC##UC%' from dual)
select listagg (str) within group ( order by lev)
from (
        select regexp_substr(s, '(^|#UC%)(.*?)(%UC#)', 1, level, '', 2) || 
               UPPER(regexp_substr(s, '(%UC#)(.*?)(#UC%)', 1, level, '', 2)) as str,
               level as lev
        from test
        connect by instr(s, '%UC#', 1, level ) > 0
     )
```

which gives ( I used `UPPER` instead of `UNISTR` to make the result clear):

```
Hello World ABC. How are you DEF. Have a nice day GHI.
```

The idea here is to use a commonly used split string technique, considering the parts wrapped by `'%UC#...#UC%'` as a separator; notice that I added a small string (`'%UC##UC%'`) to the input string to handle the last part of the input string, making the query consider the string to process as ended by and (empty) `'%UC#...#UC%'`  sequence.

In Oracle 10g we can not use `listagg` neither `regexp_substr` the way I did, hence, the solution is a bit more complicated.

Here I use no regular expressions at all and compute the aggregation by the means of `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`; to do this, I need to identify a string that will never appear in your input text, say `'@@'`:

```
with test as ( select 'Hello World %UC#abc#UC%. How are you %UC#def#UC%. Have a nice day %UC#ghi#UC%.' || '%UC##UC%' as s from dual)
```

with test as ( select 'Hello World %UC#abc#UC%. How are you %UC#def#UC%. Have a nice day %UC#ghi#UC%.' || '%UC##UC%' as s from dual)

```
select replace ( sys_connect_by_path (
                              substr(s, case when level = 1 then 1 else instr(s,'#UC%', 1, level-1) +4 end, instr(s, '%UC#', 1, level) -case when level = 1 then 1 else instr(s,'#UC%', 1, level-1) +4 end  ) || 
                              UPPER(substr(s, instr(s, '%UC#', 1, level) + 4, instr(s,'#UC%', 1, level) - (instr(s, '%UC#', 1, level) + 4)) )
                            , '@@'
                           ),
                 '@@') str                 
from test
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
connect by instr(s, '%UC#', 1, level ) > 0
```

Comment: I ran the above query and it resulted in error. `Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 10
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing`

Comment: Just edited to show a solution that should work in 10g

Comment: The 2nd query says `from` is missing. I added `from` dual at the end of the query and now it says `ORA-00904: "S": invalid identifier`

Comment: Perfect. This should be one of the great query I have come across. Thanks Aleksej.